# Is it possible to schedule a job where each result creates a separate report to be sent by JasperServer?

Tags: jasperserver

Without the aid of a separate scheduler (probably written in Java if I must go down that route) is it possible to schedule a job in JasperServer that runs some SQL and then for each row returned, runs and delivers a report?

For example the SQL would be something like:

```
select customerName, billableAmount from billing where trunc(billingdate) = trunc(sysdate);
```

This might return something like:

```
Bongo Beans, 100,000
Moon Lives, 750,000
```

I would like to then create 2 instances of my report to be sent to our accounts department, 1 for Bongo Beans, 1 for Moon Lives.

Based on everything I've read so far it seems this isn't possible but if it is, that would be magic!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HCC, I don't believe this is possible with the existing JasperReports Server scheduler, but what if you created an outer 'wrapper' report with this query, and passed the results of the query to a subreport that would run once for each result?

Comment: Thanks Lisa, I've come to the same conclusion with regards the scheduler. Shame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Lisa and my previous comments, it turns out this is not possible at present.

The solution I went for in the end was to write a java application that ran my first bit of SQL and then using the java-rest client linked below called the JaspserServer with the parameters to create my reports and then e-mail them out.

https://github.com/gkudos/jasperserver-simple-java-rest-client

Thanks for looking, hope this is helpful.